# Foreach loop inside function with sets of two variables

Tags: php, function, loops, foreach

This is a basic example of something I am trying to figure out so I can understand how to apply the same concept to other functions...

My question is for example I have a function that will create a series of links that would look something like this:

```
function link($link, $title){
    echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'"></li>';
}
```

And call it like this:

```
link('page1.html', 'Title 1', 'page2.html', 'Title 2);
```

Obviously, output should be

```
<li><a href="page1.html">Title 1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html">Title 2</a></li>
```

I am sure a foreach is involved here but again I am here asking the question so guess I don't really have a clue.  I know that I could just call link() twice or multiple times but as mentioned I want to apply this to other functions, this is just a basic example that I could think of.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function getlinks(){
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    $count = count($arguments);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+=2) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$arguments[$i].'">'.$arguments[$i+1].'</a></li>';
    }
}

getlinks('page1.html', 'Title 1', 'page2.html', 'Title 2');
```

That's a pretty basic example, you should do your checking, e.g. did you receive an even number of arguments? In this case, it could look like this:

```
    if ($count % 2 != 0) {
        $msg = "Expecting pairs of link/title, received an odd number of arguments.";
        throw new Exception(__METHOD__ . ': ' . $msg);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer Macros. actually I am also looking for the same answer